# How to get the number of <p> tags inside div in scrapy?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping this website [link](http://www.indiaconsumerforum.org/asus-zenfone-2-internet-not-working-in-sim-2/).

The last of the `<p>` tags contains the user_info and it is creating problem for me as I am using -

```
''.join(response.xpath('//div[@class="entry-content"]/p[2]/text()').extract())
```

But `p[2]` changes if the text above it is in good numbers. Say here it is `p[5]`

I am thinking of this to calculate the number of `<p>`tags inside the `div` and assign the number to my `item`

How to deal with this problem?

Comment: be aware that the `text()` at the end of your expression selects only the text nodes that are direct children, not the text nodes inside sub element (e.g. not inside `<span>text not selected</span>`)

Comment: For that I am using `//text()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, this is just the *last paragraph in the entry content* - you can use `last()`:

```
//div[@class="entry-content"]/p[last()]/text()
```

Works for me.

Comment: One more thing there is `span` class used in between `<p>` and data between that can not be extracted how to remove those `<span>`

Comment: @NikhilParmar sorry, where do you see the `span`s in the entry content?

Comment: after the first `<p>` there is span with id `IL_AD3`

Comment: You can try using `//text()` instead of `/text()`, like: `//div[@class="entry-content"]/p[last()]//text()`

Comment: @NikhilParmar `//text()` would find text nodes at any level deep in the current node.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to count the `p` elements

```
len(response.xpath('//div[@class="entry-content"]/p'))
```